# load jpeg image with exif and/or corrupted meta data

Tags: java, image, metadata

Is there any way in java to load a jpeg image with exif meta data?

I don't need the exif data(Or any other metadata), but the problem is that JavaIO.read gives me:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:995) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:966) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
        at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:940) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
```

If i try to read the images.

On an related note: We also sometimes get jpg images with other meta data which ImageIO.read can't handle either, so I would really like a jpeg reader which don't try to read/handle/understand any metadata. But I have been unable to find any.

The image data itself are newer damaged, and all other software(Gimp, Firefox and so on) can read and display the images correct.

I even tried the following, but it still can't read the images.

```
            Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");
            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader)readers.next();
            ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(sourceFile);
            reader.setInput(iis,true,true);

            BufferedImage image = reader.read(0);
```

Comment: are you sure its the metadata ? I had a similar problem with files that were encoded with CMYK. what is the color model/space of your image?

Comment: Funny story. It turned out to be meta data for some files, and color profile problems for other files. But now I just run /usr/bin/mogrify -strip on files If I can't open them, which handles most of the problems, except all the color profile problems. I still wish there was a better java library to handle jpg files with color profiles(Expecially cmyk)/stupid gamma values and similary problems (I am currently having problems with a .jpg file, which have more gamut data, then image data).

Answer (score 1):

There are not many options available here. If one wants to solve a specific issue, it can be done without a doubt in Java. Yet, if you just seek a library to do some image manipulation in your project without the need to be a graphics specialist programmer, then the open source java libraries is not yet on par with the commercial ones , or with the non Java ones.
A simple search on SO will reveal the state. Therefore, If you need to have something **reliable with minimal surprises** on a production environment, you will most probably (in my opinion) end up with one of the following (with the state as of the date of this post):

1- a commercial product, for example [Snowbound RasterMaster](http://www.snowbound.com/products/viewing-conversion-sdk/java)

2- use a tool like ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) with the option of using a java Interface for them, for example [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) or [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/).

As for your problem, you mentioned using mogrify. you can as well set the color space for the output image and it might solve your problem: [ImageMagick Colorspace](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#colorspace)

so maybe you can try :  "/usr/bin/mogrify -strip -colorspace sRGB" on your jpg files.